# DevExpress ExtraEditors checkedcombobox doesn't synchronize?

Tags: c++-cli, devexpress, checked

I'm trying to use two devExpress checkedComboBoxes (boxes) to maintain a list and its antilist (i.e, same items in both comboboxes, and they must be checked in only one of the lists).

I'm using C++/CLI, so for each box I handle

```
EditValueChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &SelectionControl::exclBox_EditValueChanged);
```

which calls through to

```
void
box_ToggleAntibox(
DevExpress::XtraEditors::CheckedComboBoxEdit^ box,
DevExpress::XtraEditors::CheckedComboBoxEdit^ antibox )
{
using namespace DevExpress::XtraEditors::Controls ;

cli::array<String ^> ^ sAnti = gcnew cli::array<String ^>(2*box->Properties->Items->Count) ;
int ii = 0;
String ^ delim = ", ";
for each (CheckedListBoxItem^ i in box->Properties->GetItems()) {
    if (i->CheckState==Windows::Forms::CheckState::Unchecked)
    {
        sAnti[ii] = i->Value->ToString();
        ++ii;
        sAnti[ii] = delim;
        ++ii;
    }
}

String ^ result = String::Concat(sAnti);
antibox->EditValue = result;

}
```

As the devExpress documentation seems to say to set the edit value, rather than simply iterating through the box list and setting the anti-list to !Checked.

However, it doesn't seem to be working (the correct items are added to the text window, but nothing is checked).  Moreover, if I look at my box after the event has finished, I find that the string value in the text window is correct (reflects what I'd selected), but if I open it up, then all items are selected.

Does anyone have any suggestions I might try?

Is it better to set each item's CheckState::Checked instead?

Thanks!

Comment: If i use `antibox->SetEditValue(result)` then both nothing is checked and nothing appears in the text window.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time talking to DevExpress support.  The short answer is that this should work - but doesn't for us.  Your mileage may vary, but our solution was to put the two comboboxes on to separate controls on the form.